# Tridion Component Behavior

Tags: 2011

I have  a  news component which is used  in  below two pages -

(a) News Page – this page have  broker API code  and display the Dynamic component presentations of various news components.

(b) News Detail Page -  These are static pages respective to each news component.

When I do any change in any such news component and publish it , changes are visible on both the pages.

I was  in impression by my Tridion concepts that i have to publish "News detail" page (static page) to see the changes. and surprised to see the changes on this page.

Though  this behavior is not against my business but want to correct my concepts here.

Is this default behavior of Tridion ?

Could somebody provide me a detailed knowledge on this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are publishing a component, the resolver resolves all necessary items that needs to be published along with it. In the publish dialog of the component if you click "Show items to publish" you will see the DCP for the news component being published which is probably used on the (a) News Page and also (b) News detail page for that component.

Update (additional info from comments):
During publishing a component a page which uses it as embedded CP will get resolved, depends on the value of the ResolveInstruction.Purpose. By default the UI uses value ResolvePurpose.RePublish which only resolves pages which are already published. In your case either the static page (b) (containing the embedded CP) was published already, or the value of the ResolvePurpose is being set to Publish.

Comment: first of all thanks  of answering. Here i have a doubt again When i see the "Show items to publish" in the publish dialog of the component,this component is only their. If i go with your points, Static page( b) should be visible in this list also.

Comment: During publishing a component a page which uses it as embedded CP will get resolved, depends on the value of the `ResolveInstruction.Purpose`. By default the UI uses value `ResolvePurpose.RePublish` which only resolves pages which are already published. In your case either the static page (b) (containing the embedded CP) was published already, or the value of the `ResolvePurpose` is being set to `Publish`.

Comment: @Likhan you should expand on your answer to also include the contents of your comment.

Answer (score 3):

As per the default Tridion Behaviour if you publish a Component - All the possible Dynamic Component Presentation will get publish along with all the pages it has been included on as a static component presentation.

For example: Consider following scenario:

- A component Comp_A is created with a schema Schema_A
- There are Dynamic Component Presentations - CT_A, CT_B & CT_C having Schema_A as a linked schema
- There are static Component Presentation - CT1
- There are pages Page1, Page2, Page3 having Comp_A + CT1 as static CP embedded on the page

Now if you publish the Comp_A - It will publish Page1, Page2 and Page3 as well as publish all DCP in broker DB making 3 entries in the Broker DB - one each for CT_A, CT_B & CT_C

On the other hand - If you publish Page1 or Page2 or Page3 then (By Default) only the respective page as a consolidated Presentation will get publish.